# Stop Drag, Add Up Release for a separate function

Tags: actionscript-3, parent-child, flash-cs5, drag

I have a movie clip where I've placed start drag and stop drag actions, and I'd like to activate a button action (run a movie clip named person_mo) with the ReleaseToDrop function. However, I cannot code it correctly. Here is the AS I have for the drag:

```
stop();

/* Drag and Drop
Makes the specified symbol instance moveable with drag and drop.
*/

SCOPE2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_ClickToDrag);

function fl_ClickToDrag(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    SCOPE2.startDrag();
}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_ReleaseToDrop);

function fl_ReleaseToDrop(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    SCOPE2.stopDrag();
}
```

How can I play the person_mo movie clip and stop the drag?

Comment: What is the language you are using?

Comment: AS3 in Flash CS5 is what I'm working in.

Answer (score 0):

After I tested your code, your `stopDrag` function is working well. You just need to fire your event/function/ command when you fire the ReleaseToDrop function.

```
stop();

/* Drag and Drop
Makes the specified symbol instance moveable with drag and drop.
*/

SCOPE2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_ClickToDrag);

function fl_ClickToDrag(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    SCOPE2.startDrag();
}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_ReleaseToDrop);

function fl_ReleaseToDrop(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    SCOPE2.stopDrag();
    person_mo.play(); // if you want to run the movie clip 
    yourFunction(); //or else if you want a function to fire, simply add yourFunction which fires the button action.


}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: What function should I use to fire/play the person_button, which is nested in the person_mo movie clip. I ask because with the code in the response, the movie flashes back and forth with no interaction.

Comment: If it's within person_mo movie clip, then you might change your function code as  person_mo.yourFunction(); You see, you cannot play a button. There must be a function that fires or plays your person_button. If person_button were a movieclip, the code would be person_mo,person_button.play();    or  person_mo.person_button.yourFunction();  Your screen is blinking because in my code, "yourFunction" is something that depends on your code. It's an example that you need to edit and change the function name. It is showing an error, hence blinking becayse "yourFunction" doesn't exist in your code